# Updating stocks quantity in Product Table from Cart

Tags: java, php, sql

Hello everyone so basically I have this 2 tables

[ProductLists](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hoKlM.png)

and

[Cart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7BMX.png)

Note: Cart table contains temporary datas inside it, if the orders inside cart table are already paid the table itself will truncate.

I tried running this query

```
UPDATE productlists
SET stocks = stocks - (SELECT SUM(QTY) FROM cart WHERE ID = productlists.product_id)
```

and this happened [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/upfoc.png)

any advice on how to do this without making the stocks of the other products go Null?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for MSSQL:

```
UPDATE productlists
SET stocks = stocks - Q.QTY
FROM (
    SELECT 
        ID,
        SUM(QTY) as QTY
    FROM 
        cart 
    GROUP BY
        ID
    ) Q
WHERE productlists.product_id = Q.ID
```

For phpMyAdmin:

```
update productlists set stocks = stocks - (select sum(QTY) from cart where ID = productlists.product_id) where product_id in (select ID FROM cart);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: hello, thanks for answering but it doesn't work it says theres a syntax error. I tried to use that query in SQL Server and it works fine, but what im using in this project is phpmyadmin. 

https://imgur.com/85zyfe8

Comment: @Jiyo I've updated my answer, you have to update only items that are in your cart, so you need to add condition for that

Comment: The stocks now doesn't appear as null and this worked perfectly as I wanted! thank you!